# How to catch the JSON data in React.js web application(front-end) which is coming from Remote URL

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, sockets

We tried using componentdidmount, here we could fetch data from an API using Get request and print on console. But here our requirement is not to fetch data from API, we want to catch data which is coming from remote url remoteurlexample.com and print the values on console.

What we have tried :-

```
import React,{ Component } from "react";
import axios from 'axios'
class PostList extends Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state={
            posts: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('remoteurlexample.com',{ 'headers' : { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*'}})
            .then(response => {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(response)) 
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
            })
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                List of posts
            </div>
        )
    }

}
export default PostList
```

**It is not working as expected**

Sample image for understanding question:-

[image: He is the sample image for understanding the question better]

Please do help on this guys or let me know is another way to achieve it.

Thank you

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: nothing is printing brother,

Comment: what is the output of `console.log()` either from `.then` or `catch`?

Comment: It is printing the response data

Comment: Do you want to catch the error data?

Comment: @ChetanKumar brother actully i want to print the data which is coming as a json to frontend from remote url (basically i am posting some data to https://example.com from remote server), is it possible?

Comment: @Vaibhav output is none bro

Comment: it is working with no errors, if yo are using chrome just ensure to disable the "Enable javascript source maps"  and "Enable CSS source maps" else it will through an error

Comment: @RAJENDRAH
Your data is being printed in console.log as you wish. There are no errors.

I guess you want to render this data. You want to parse this JSON data to HTML.

Am I right?

Comment: @Feras and Chetan Kumar , hey guys, as i described about the issue i am not getting any error, the problem is when ever data posted from remote url to https://exapmle.com, 
https://exapmle.com is not triggering that means this code is not working, so i wanted to know is there any way to achieve it or have i done code wrong?.

Thank you